# Regex - Counting greatest number of short tandem repeats

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics

Im looping through a list of Short Tandem Repeats and trying to find the greatest amount of times they occur **consecutively** in a sequence of DNA.

Sequence:

```
AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGAGATCAGATCAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAGATCAGATC
```

```py
STRs = ['AGATC', 'AATG', 'TATC']

for STR in STRs:
    max_repeats = len(re.findall(f'(?<={STR}){STR}', sequence))
    print(max_repeats)
```

The greatest amount of consecutive repeats in the sequence is 4
[image: STR]

My current regex is only returning 3 matches because of the positive lookbehind, I'm also not too sure how to modify my code to capture the greatest amount of repeats (4) without also including the other repeat groups, is it possible to retrieve a nested list of the matches which I could iterate over to find the greatest number like below.

```py
[[AGATC, AGATC, AGATC, AGATC], [AGATAC,AGATC], [AGATC, AGATC]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is nothing dynamic in the string that you're searching for, and *especially* when the string that you are searching in is large, I would try to find a solution that avoids regex, because basic string methods typically are significantly faster than regex.

The following is probably un-Pythonic in more ways than one (improvement suggestions welcome), but the underlying assumption is that `str.split()` massively outperforms regex, and the arithmetic to calculate string positions takes negligible time.

```
def find_tandem_repeats(sequence, search):
    """ searches through an DNA sequence and returns (position, repeats) tuples """
    if sequence == '' or search == '':
        return

    lengths = list(map(len, sequence.split(search)))
    pos = lengths[0]
    repeats = 0
    pending = False

    for l in lengths[1:]:
        if l == 0:
            pending = True
            repeats += 1
            continue
        repeats += 1
        yield (pos, repeats)
        pos += l + len(search) * repeats
        repeats = 0
        pending = False

    if pending:
        yield (pos, repeats)
```

usage:

```
data = "AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGAGATCAGATCAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAGATCAGATC"
positions = list(find_tandem_repeats(data, 'AGATC'))

for position in positions:
    print("at index %s, repeats %s times" % position)

max_position = max(positions, key=lambda x: x[1])
print("maximum at index %s, repeats %s times" % max_position)
```

Output

```
at index 55, repeats 4 times
at index 104, repeats 2 times
at index 171, repeats 2 times
maximum at index 55, repeats 4 times
```

Comment: I didn't realise string methods were faster than regex, I though the sole of purpose of regex was to find patterns in text and thus would be optimised for that. A lot of the regex answers have gone over my head but at least I can start to comprehend this If I go over the code line by line.

Comment: Yes, that's the sole purpose of regex. But regex do *a lot* more work than a simple loop that splits a string. Regex are *significantly* slower, it's worth doing a comparison especially on large input sizes. Simple string operations cannot find patterns, but you don't have patterns - you have substrings.

Comment: @kish-an By all means, do a comparison, don't take me for my words alone. Also, I only have tested a couple of simple cases on short strings, please test thoroughly on your real data.

Comment: The reason why I went with `str.split()` and not with a loop over `str.index()` is that `split` is a single call that runs fully in C code and is highly optimized. `index` takes multiple calls to reach the end of the string. Downside of `split` is that it allocates memory for the parts it returns, which basically get thrown away immediately. `index` could in theory operate on the same string instance without ever needing to allocate new memory. This could be beneficial for multiple searches on the same input string.

Comment: Ah I see, the premium here would definitely be performance rather than memory but I think it'll be interesting to compare this against a regex solution. I appreciate all the help!

Comment: If you do a comparison, use a real-world scenario (realistic input sizes and searches) and publish your findings, I'm very interested. Allocating memory costs time too, so optimizing out allocations can grant an additional bonus. The more often the same DNA sequence is searched for different things, the more important this will become.

Answer (score 1):

To find all sequences of **AGATC** as long as it's not at the end of the sequence, you can use:

```py
>>> re.findall(r'AGATC\B', sequence)
['AGATC', 'AGATC', 'AGATC', 'AGATC']
```

From [the python documentation on `\B`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-27):

> Matches the empty string, but only when it is *not* at the beginning or end of a word. This means that `r'py\B'` matches `'python'`, `'py3'`, `'py2'`, but not `'py'`, `'py.'`, or `'py!'`. `\B` is just the opposite of `\b`, so word characters in Unicode patterns are Unicode alphanumerics or the underscore, although this can be changed by using the `ASCII` flag. Word boundaries are determined by the current locale if the `LOCALE` flag is used.

Comment: Your answer made me realise I worded my question poorly, apologies! I'm actually looking to retrieve the greatest amount of repeats from the sequence, I've edited my post to reflect this. `\B` matches the repeat sequence properly which is much better than my original regex but now I'm running into the issue of isolating the greatest number of consecutive repeats as I'm getting back a list of 7 STRs, which includes the 4 repeats at the start + 2 repeats in the middle + 1 at the end.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's one way to approach the problem:**

```
>>> STRs = ['AGATC', 'AATG', 'TATC']
>>> pattern = '|'.join(f'({tgt})+' for tgt in STRs)
>>> for mo in re.finditer(pattern, seq):
         print(mo.group(0))

AGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC
TATCTATCTATCTATCTATC
AGATCAGATC
AATG
AGATCAGATC
```

**Key ideas:**

1) The core pattern used `+` for a group to allow for **consecutive** repeats:

```
(AGATC)+
```

2) The patterns are combined with `|` to allow any STR to match:

```
>>> pattern
'(AGATC)+|(AATG)+|(TATC)+'
```

3) The *re.finditer()* call gives the match objects one at a time.

4) If needed the match object can give other information like start and stop points to compute length or a tuple to show which STR matched:

```
>>> mo.group(0)
'AGATCAGATC'
>>> mo.span()
(171, 181)
>>> mo.groups()
('AGATC', None, None)
```

**How to count the maximum repetitions:**

```
>>> tracker = dict.fromkeys(STRs, 0)
>>> for mo in re.finditer(pattern, seq):
        start, end = mo.span()
        STR = next(filter(None, mo.groups()))
        reps = (end - start) // len(STR)
        tracker[STR] = max(tracker[STR], reps)

>>> tracker
{'AGATC': 4, 'AATG': 1, 'TATC': 5}
```

Comment: That seems to work really well to isolate the repeat sequences, however what would be the best way to find the greatest amount of repeats for each STR from the output match object as they are not stored in a list like `re.findall`

Comment: @kish-an Keep a running count in of repeats in a dictionary and update it during the loop.

Comment: `max(len(x[0])//len(x[1]) for x in re.findall(r'((ab|bc)\2+)', 'ababababbcbcbcababab'))` is a prototype which does that, I was preparing a similar answer but took too long...

Comment: @kish-an I've expanded the answer to show how to accumulate the maximum sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional programming approach. In each recursion step the first occurrences of a consecutive repeat is found and after that eliminated from the search string. You keep record of the maximum of repeats found so far and pass it to each recursive call until no consecutive repeats are found anymore.

```
def find_repeats (pattern, seq, max_r=0):
    g = re.search(f'{pattern}({pattern})+', seq)
    if g:
        max_repeats = len ( g.group() ) / len(pattern)
        return find_repeats (pattern, seq.replace (g.group(), '', 1), max (max_r, max_repeats) )
    else:
        return max_r

print (find_repeats ('AGATC', sequence))
```